# Why are there topological no results on halfspace arrangements?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, computational-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

After doing some searching around, I've come to realize that while there is a huge body of literature on hyperplane arrangements, not much is generally written about *halfspace arrangements*. Is there any reason for this?

Does one imply or relate to the other some how?

As an example, I might want to ask what the homology of some arbitrary set expression on an arragnement is: Given a set of affine halfspaces $A = \{A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and some set expression $$E(A) = (A_1 \cap A_2 \cup A_3 \cap (A_2^c))^c \cap A_n$$
Then what is $H_p(E(A); \mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: The boundary of a half-space is a hyperplane. As per the notions I'm used to, an arrangement of half-spaces would differ from an arrangement of hyperplanes only by labelling which cells lie on what side of each individual hyperplane. Assuming you already have an arrangement of hyperplanes, you could do the labelling in time linear wrt the size of the arrangement.

Comment: Well, what do you want to know about them exactly? Your question is more or less unanswerable as it is.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez updated

Comment: @N.Bach Are you aware of any algorithms which actually compute the number of regions in the compliment of a hyperplane arrangement for example?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Assuming "regions" are "cells" of the arrangement, what even is the complement of an arrangement? Cells of an arrangement span the whole space. If you specify a few cells, then sure you can always figure out how many cells you've left out.